# How can I determine what MTD flash device is installed (e.g. get the ID or serial number)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Using uClinux we have one of two flash devices installed, a 1GB flash or a 2GB flash.

The only way I can think of solving this is to somehow get the device ID - which is down the in the device driver code, for me that is in:

`drivers/mtd/devices/m25p80.c`

I have been using the command `mtdinfo` (which comes from mtdutils binaries, derived from mtdinfo.c/h). There is various information stored in here about the flash partitions including flash type 'nor' eraseblock size '65536', etc. But nothing that I can identify the chip with.

Its not very clear to me how I can get information from "driver-land" into "user-land". I am looking at trying to extend the mtdinfo command to print more information but there are many layers...

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you gain useful information by querying the block devices, e.g. by using the 'blockdev' command?  If you have a block device for the whole mtd device, you could query that, otherwise you'd have to query the block devices of the individual mtd partitions. Sometimes, the final mtd partition is auto-sized to fill the remaining space in the underlying mtd device.

Comment: @IanAbbott nice idea - I used the `blockdev --getsize /dev/mtdblock5` (the last block) and it showed me the size of the last actual block, not the remaining size : (  ... I tried all the other blocks too just in case there was any extra info, but they are all the expected partition sizes.

Comment: There is a kernel config option to create a block device for the whole mtd, but using that might bump up your existing /dev/mtdblock numbers by one. The config option is `CONFIG_MTD_PARTITIONED_MASTER` "Retain master device when partitioned".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, I have found no easy way to do this without code changes. However I have found an easy code change (probably a bit of a hack) that allows me to get the information I need:

In the relevant file (in my case `drivers/mtd/devices/m25p80.c`) you can call one of the following:

```
dev_err("...");
dev_alert("...");
dev_warn("...");
dev_notice("...");
_dev_info("...");
```

Which are defined in `include/Linux/device.h`, so they are part of the Linux driver interface so you can use them from any driver.

I found that the dev_err() and devalert() both get printed out "on screen" during run time. However all of these device messages can be found in `/var/log/messages`. Since I added messages in the format: `dev_notice("JEDEC id %06x\n", jedecid);`, I could find the device ID with the following command:

`cat /var/log/messages | grep -i jedec`

Obviously using `dev_err()` or`dev_alert()` is not quite right! - but `dev_notice()` or even `_dev_info()` seem more appropriate.

Not yet marking this as the answer since it requires code changes - still hoping for a better solution if anyone knows of one...

**Update**

Although the above "solution" works, its a bit crappy - certainly will do the job and good enough for mucking around. But I decided that if I am making code changes I may as well do it properly. So I have now implemented changes to add an interface in sysfs such that you can get the flash id with the following command:

`cat /sys/class/m25p80/m25p80_dev0/device_id`

The main function calls required for this are (in this order):

```
alloc_chrdev_region(...)
class_create(...)
device_create(...)
sysfs_create_group(...)
```

This should give enough of a hint for anyone wanting to do the same, though I can expand on that answer if anyone wants it.

Comment: Is your sysfs solution available somewhere?